# ASP.net and it's version

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and now following through the http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part1.htm howto.

All is fine except of when code is falling with exception i see

```
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

but at project properties 3.5 is selected.
what is wrong and how to fix it?

ps: i'm running code directly from VS2008 (by pressing ctrl+f5) without any dedicated IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is actually wrong. That version number you see refers to the [Common Language Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) version, which is the same in versions 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 of the .NET Framework.

Comment: As @PatrickJ says, the CLR version did not change. Also, ASP.NET core did not change... literally, the development team was not allowed to touch it. All the new "ASP.NET 3.5" functionality is in add-ons such as ASP.NET AJAX, new data source controls for LINQ and Entities. template and routing support for ASP.NET dynamic data (actually, that's 3.5 service pack 1). But ASP.NET did not change in 3.5. Yes, it's confusing, but as long as your project is configured for the 3.5 framework, then everything is fine.

Comment: That's right, because under the surface they all use the 2.0 Common Language Runtime. Check out the link I posted to get a better example of what it is and how it relates to the rest of the framework and language, it will make a little more sense then.